# How i can check if a user is logged-in in PHP from application

Tags: c#, php, mysql, visual-studio

I made an application, and i tried to make like this, but when i exit from the app, the user is still online:

1. To have in DB a column called loggedin which is INT, 0 = off, 1 = on.
2. And at every login the int is set to 1.
3. And at exit i made an other php file which is called logout, and set loggedin to 0.

But is still 1 because the app don't have time to set-it back to 0, and i can make a timer but is the app crashes then will be still 0.

Any idea how i can do that?

P.S. i use PHP and C# to protect the DB password, i don't want to use the DB password in the Application code.

Comment: I think you should use a token and check when the user enters the app...

Comment: "..i use PHP and C# to protect the DB password.."... what?

Comment: @Tony Samperi how i can use a token,
 Vodoo i am using PHP an c#, i mean i son't use the DB password in the Application code.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. I think you are asking how to have your `C#` script send a request to your PHP on the closing event, is that correct?

Comment: @chris85, no, i mean i did that but if the user exit the app or app crashes the in DB the user is still on, because the application don't have time to change "loggedin" back to 0, and i want an better way to check if the user is online in the application.

Comment: The only thing I could think of would be a sending a request every 30 seconds or minute to confirm still active (maybe updating a lastactive column which is datetime or timestamp). If no response after X minutes/seconds have a CRON that sets the user to logged out.

Comment: @chris85 how i can do that?

Comment: I don't know about the C#. The CRON would be something like `update usersactive set active = 0 where lastactive > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 SECOND`

Comment: @chris85, well idk where i need to add that line.

Comment: It'd be in the PHP and run by CRON on your server, I don't know the `C#` aspect, the PHP/mysql brought me here.